# Does this type of matrix with the same diagonals have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, terminology

Given real numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_n$, we define the real symmetric matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\color{red}{x_1} &    \color{red}{x_1} & \color{red}{x_1} & \cdots & \color{red}{x_1} \\ 
\color{red}{x_1} &    \color{blue}{x_2} & \color{blue}{x_2} & \color{blue}{\cdots} & \color{blue}{x_2} \\
\color{red}{x_1} &    \color{blue}{x_2} & \color{green}{x_3} & \cdots & \color{green}{x_3} \\
\color{red}{\vdots} & \color{blue}{\vdots} &  \color{green}{\vdots} & \ddots & \\ 
\color{red}{x_1} & \color{blue}{x_2} & \color{green}{x_3} & \cdots & x_n  
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So this matrix has all diagonals of the form $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_n$.

Does this matrix have a name? If not, I am curious if anything can be said about its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matrix is known with the name MIN matrix and is well studied in ([Kilic & Arican, 2019, Studying new generalizations of Max-Min matrices with a novel approach](https://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1455&context=math)) and in ([Mattila & Haukkanen, 2016, Studying the various properties of MIN and MAX matrices - elementary vs. more advanced methods](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/spma-2016-0010/html?lang=en)).